# Create Method/Answer Method from caller

Tags: c#

I have quite a weird question to do here. Due to reflection I am pointing a class to my mock class instead of the "real" class. (Testing purposes). I'd like to know if there is any way of catching in the mock any method call, and returning whatever I want depending on what the calling is waiting.

Some sort of:

An object that calls another object to do X() and expects a bool.

As I have changed with reflection the object it points to, I'd like my mock to return "true" when X() is called on him (although it doesn't have X() implemented itself).

In other words, instead of firing an "MethodNotFoundException", to receive everything and do some logic accordingly.

Comment: You can look into a Dependency Injection (DI) framework like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) that will solve this sort of problem.

Comment: Can't you do a catch, for MethodNotFoundException? You are expecting it to happen in some cases, and you can include your custom logic in there.

Comment: I think you're in the wrong language here...

Comment: (You could *maybe* do something with [`System.Dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.aspx) but it's going to be neither simple nor straightforward.)

Comment: Can you post some code samples?

Comment: Jay: Im sorry to say that a framework won't help for this :(
StephenBorg: The catch im looking on should happen on the mock, which is impossible (AFAIK). The other objects cannot be changed.
@millimoose: I'll look for that! Lets see if it helps.
AlexFilipovici Hmmm, I may do it tomorrow if you need it :)

Thanks again all.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici I think he basically wants [`method_missing`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing). A way to catch anything that looks like a method call and dynamically determine what to do.

Comment: @charlypu One thing that comes to mind is that it's pretty unlikely that anything you do with `System.Dynamic` will get you any sort of static type information, like what the result of the method call was supposed to be. I believe that .NET handles `dynamic` expressions in a fundamentally different way than regular statically typed code. The feature is intended to enable interoperability with dynamically typed languages, not as a metaprogramming facility.

Comment: @millimoose Method_missing from that link was really helpful. Just a search in Google for the version in C# and I got it, I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @millimoose, the best approach (and quite an easy one) is:

DynamicObject.TryInvoke Method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryinvoke.aspx

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the exception you are getting is [MissingMethodException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.missingmethodexception.aspx).
Maybe the following console application could guide you towards a more specific implementation, but the logic should be the same:

```
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// a dictionary for holding the desired return values
    /// </summary>
    static Dictionary<string, object> _testReturnValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // adding the test return for method X
        _testReturnValues.Add("X", true);

        var result = ExecuteMethod(typeof(MyClass), "X");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static object ExecuteMethod(Type type, string methodName)
    {
        try
        {
            return type.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, null);
        }
        catch (MissingMethodException e)
        {
            // getting the test value if the method is missing
            return _testReturnValues[methodName];
        }
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    //public static string X() 
    //{
    //    return "Sample return";
    //}
}
```